# Histogram of the 1D-random walk in Julia

Tags: python, random, julia, histogram, random-walk

This is a simulation of 100 1D-random "walkers" each taking 100 "steps" in either one direction or another by +1/-1.

```
using Plots
init = 0
walkers = 100
walk_length = 100
walks = cumsum(vcat(fill(init, 1, walkers),               # initial state
                    rand([-1, 1], walk_length, walkers)), # vertically append move direction
               dims=1)  # cumulative sum over the first dimension to get one walk per column
plot(walks, legend=nothing)
```

[image]

Since many walkers can end up at the same value at 100 steps, I would like to create a histogram at the end point, showing the amount of walkers there. 
I think there might be a `hist()` function but I am not sure how to implement it.

Comment: why are you asking the questions incrementally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
histogram(walks[end, :], bins=20, legend=nothing)
```

[image]